# Get each checked checkbox value

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to get the value of each checked box that has been selected as true. Each time I select a checkbox it grabs the value of that checkbox instead of all the selected checkboxes.

Path: `talentList.html`

```
<fieldset>        
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="specialisation" type="checkbox" value="Accounting Firm"> Accounting Firm
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="specialisation" type="checkbox" value="Accounting in Industry"> Accounting in Industry
    </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Path: `talentList.js`

```
Template.talentList.events({
    'change [name="specialisation"]': function ( event, template ) {
        let specialisation = event.target.value;
        template.candidateListFilter.set( specialisation );
    }
});
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your problem is. Are you trying to get all the selected checkbox values whenever you select a checkbox?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one *target* set in the event handler so `event.target.value` will be a scalar instead of an array. You need to iterate over the array of checkboxes.

```
Template.talentList.events({
  'change [name="specialisation"]': function ( event, template ) {
    $.each($('[name="specialisation"]'),function(i,cb){
      let specialisation = cb.value;
      template.candidateListFilter.set( specialisation );
    });
  }
});
```

To be honest this seems like an odd pattern. If you want to update a document whenever a checkbox is checked/unchecked you shouldn't have to set the state of all the other checkboxes at the same time, you should be able to just poke the one you want.

Comment: Add "[name='specialisation']:checked" so it only grabbed the selected checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is correct. It creates an object of all selected options.

```
'change [name="specialisation"]': function ( event, template ) {

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var specialisation = $('input[name="specialisation"]:checked').map(function(){

            return $(this).val();

        });

        var specialisationListArray = specialisation.get();
        template.candidateListFilter.set( specialisationListArray );
    });
},
```